# What Happens When Multiple Fields with the Same Name have Different Boosts?

Tags: lucene

[Boost is by-Field in Lucene](http://makble.com/lucene-field-boost-example), and that is then set in the Index. You can add multiple Fields with the Name property set to the same value, and they'll then be searched for that Document as though you just added the union of those Terms to that Document under that Field name.

```
var field1 = new Field("Text", "aquaculture");
var field2 = new Field("Text", "fish");
field1.setBoost(1.0f);
field2.setBoost(2.0f);
var doc = new Document();
doc.AddField(field1);
doc.AddField(field2);
```

But you can set the Boost to multiple values as you do so - if you do, what happens? Do the Terms in each Field get set to the separate Boost levels, or does one shared Boost level get used? If one, is it Last-In, First-In, random?

(The above code is pseudocode just to illustrate the Fields getting added to a single Doc to help coders visualize it, I realize the actual code to do the above is a bit different in actual Lucene API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the current version of Lucene, this question is no longer relevant. Setting boosts on fields was deprecated in 6.5, and no longer supported in 7.0. See [LUCENE-6819](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6819) for discussion. The replacement, per the [migration guide](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_0/MIGRATE.html):

> ...index-time scoring factors should be indexed in a doc value field and combined with the score at query time using FunctionScoreQuery for instance.

---

In previous versions, if multiple boosts added to the same field, they are multiplied. This specified by the [FieldInvertState](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_2/core/org/apache/lucene/index/FieldInvertState.html#getBoost--), which is the information that gets passed to the Similarity, which performs the translation of that data into what gets stored in the index.

> This is the cumulative product of document boost and field boost for all field instances sharing the same field name.

Comment: Interesting problem; I'm on Lucene.Net, which is version 4.8, so the multiple Field boosts is still very much relevant. If I'm understanding version history correctly, document boosts went away in favor of Field boosts somewhere around the transition from 3.0 to 4.0, so it's almost too bad to see it migrate back to documents in a future version. That said, it does seem more correct, since multiply on multiple Field additions is not at all what I would intuit as the outcome.